# NERDTreeMenu Remapping

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-nerdtree, keyboard-layout

I'm a Colemak keyboard layout user and I recently started to learn and use Vim.

I was able to map the arrow keys in the `normal` mode by putting custom mappings such as `noremap u k` in .vimrc (because the keys `h`, `j`, `k`, and `i` are in different places in the Colemak layout).

However, when I tried to use NERDTree, navigating through the NERDTree menu became very hard for me for I have to reach `j` and `k` key to navigate up and down (those keys are `y` and `k` in QWERTY).

Is there a way to map those two keys into other keys?

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you look at the documentation (`:help NERDTree-t`), you'll see that each of the command have a name and a default key.

To remap for example `NERDTreeMapUpdir` to the 'a' key, you just have to add to you `.vimrc`:

```
let NERDTreeMapUpdir='a'
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! It wasn't working when I tried to set `let NERDTreeMenuDown = "e"` and the reason was that the key `e` has been bound to something else, so by setting the `NERDTreeMapOpenExpl` to some other key solved the issue.

Comment: sidenote: when I made the change instantly in `:ex`, like `:let NERD...='x'` this didn't work. Also changing this in vimrc and then `:source` it didn't work. Somehow I had to restart vim for the change in vimrc to take effect